# Retrieve custom data from in app messaging campaign in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

[image]

Hello flutter developers. I'm trying to retrieve custom data from firebase in app messaging campaign. Anybody knows.??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.